# Creating "Favorites" Button in Swift - Xcode 6

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am working on setting up a "add to favorites" button and here is where I am. I have added a UIButton to my table view and I want to set a key as true when clicked and change the image. Then if clicked again it will set the same key as false and change the image back to the default.

Here is my code so far:

```
let isCouponFav = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isCouponFav");
```

The button is set to "Touch Up Inside" to call function favButtonTapped()

```
@IBAction func favButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
  if isCouponFav == true{
    NsUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "isCouponFav");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
    let image = UIImage(named: "Heart_icon.png")
    sender.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  }
  else{
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isCouponFav");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
    let image = UIImage(named: "heart_icon_selected.png")
    sender.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  }
}
```

As of right now - The heart will change to the "heart_icon_selected" when clicked but will not change back to "Heart_icon" when clicked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you didn't change the value of `isCoupnFav` after click the button, therefore `isCouponFav` is always true/false, based on the initial value in this line:

```
let isCouponFav = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isCouponFav")
```

You can change the code to this: (Updated to Swift 3 syntax)

```
// To make change to isCouponFav, you need to declare it as variable
// not a constant
var isCouponFav = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isCouponFav")
...

@IBAction func favButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    if isCouponFav {
        let image = UIImage(named: "Heart_icon.png")
        sender.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    } else {
        let image = UIImage(named: "heart_icon_selected.png")
        sender.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }

    isCouponFav = !isCouponFav
    UserDefaults.standard.set(isCouponFav, forKey: "isCouponFav")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

And, in Swift you don't need `;` at the end of line.

Comment: isCouponFav = !isCouponFav - it is telling me "Cannot assign to 'isCouponFav' in 'self'

Comment: oh yes, because you make it a constant. Please read my edited answer.

Comment: So sorry if this is a dumb question. But I am new to Swift and still trying to learn the best practices. For something like this - can I save into this key and pass it from controller-to-controller or should I save into a database and call it from there?

Comment: yes you can, values that saved in `NSUserDefaults` can be used in all view controller.